# I do I get QDialog geometry to expand in fullscreen?

Tags: qt

I'm trying to get a fullscreen dialog to launch after clicking a button in my MainWindow using QT on Mac. I use showFullScreen() to display the dialog, and the whole screen does get taken up. The problem is that the widgets within the dialog are still constrained to the 1024px geometry set for the dialog in the designer, and positioned in the upper left corner of the screen. I can manually change the geometry in the ui file to match my desktop, but I can't get it to work programmatically. I have tried setting the geometry of the dialog to desktop()->geometry() and the running updateGeometry() and that did not work. I tried it both before and after running the showFullScreen() function.

I've tried setting the sizePolicy of the dialog to Expandable, Maximum, Preferred, and just about every other setting, and still no go. Right now it is an absolute bare bones project, show the only code to show would be the sessionscreen.showFullScreen() function in the button_clicked() slot.

I'm sure there is something I'm missing, but I have been at it for hours, scouring Google and Qt help forums and coming up empty. Hopefully someone can point out something very simple that I am missing.

Comment: Maybe it's will be good if you add some code to your question?

Comment: Aside from the autogenerated code, the only code I have added is sessionscreen.showFullScreen(), where sessionscreen is the dialog.

Comment: Do you know how to work with layouts? May be that's the problem...

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in the post. I have placed a layout in the dialog itself. To test the layout, I put just a horizontal layout with a button. The button expanded to take up the whole dialog in the designer. But when I run it full screen, the button is still the 1024px width of the dialog and not the 1600px of the screen. Do I need to put the dialog itself in a layout? If so, I don't know how to do that from within designer. Do I need to do it in code?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I am indeed using layouts wrong, because the widgets don't move if i resize the layout in designer either. I thought I followed the tutorial videos exactly. This is why I prefer text based tutorials. Oh well, back to Youtube I go.

Comment: top-level layout missing? Make sure normal resizing works in designer (preview).

Comment: It is very easy to learn how the Qt layouts work. Just take a look in a book. You can't be satisfyed with your code if you you do not possess layouts.